# How to merge all xts objects in an environment

Tags: r, environment, xts

I would like to combine all the (xts) objects that are in a new environment that I created. The best I came up with is the following using the `eapply` function. I used `eapply` because it takes all the objects in the environment and I cannot come up with something better.

This will take the head of the values in each object, but I want the whole object.

```
plist <- eapply(dataEnv, head)  
pframe <- do.call(merge, plist)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the entire object, you can simply convert the environment to a list. Then merge using `do.call()`, like you've already done.  For example:

```
library(quantmod)
e <- new.env()
getSymbols("IBM;MSFT", env = e)
pframe <- do.call(merge, as.list(e))
head(pframe)
#            IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03    97.18    98.40   96.26     97.27    9196800     76.18299
# 2007-01-04    97.25    98.79   96.88     98.31   10524500     76.99751
# 2007-01-05    97.60    97.95   96.91     97.42    7221300     76.30047
# 2007-01-08    98.50    99.50   98.35     98.90   10340000     77.45959
# 2007-01-09    99.08   100.33   99.07    100.07   11108200     78.37598
# 2007-01-10    98.50    99.05   97.93     98.89    8744800     77.45180
#            MSFT.Open MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume MSFT.Adjusted
# 2007-01-03     29.91     30.25    29.40      29.86    76935100      23.08097
# 2007-01-04     29.70     29.97    29.44      29.81    45774500      23.04231
# 2007-01-05     29.63     29.75    29.45      29.64    44607200      22.91091
# 2007-01-08     29.65     30.10    29.53      29.93    50220200      23.13508
# 2007-01-09     30.00     30.18    29.73      29.96    44636600      23.15826
# 2007-01-10     29.80     29.89    29.43      29.66    55017400      22.92637
```

Comment: thank you! In fact before I posted, I tried to do that but got some mysterious error message. It works now )))